# Amazon EC2 Django Static Files configuration

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Configured an Amazon EC2 yesterday. Went through holy complete Google. No luck no work around. I am really unsure what next needs to test to get my static files running.

I share my working local system Django configuration:

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ui',
)

TEMPLATE_DIR = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'website/ui/templates/'),
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "website/ui/static"),
)
```

Now the thing is `TEMPLATE_DIR` is working fine.

**index.html**

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
...
...
<img src="{% static 'images/logo.jpg' %}" width="100" height="100" />
...
...
```

Specific configuration that I did on EC2 is:

I have followed instructions from this blog: [Deploying Django on AWS](http://nickpolet.com/blog/deploying-django-on-aws/1/)

Now my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` contains `test_site.com.conf` with the below data:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/v1/app-info/app/website/website/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/v1/app-info/app/website
<Directory /home/ubuntu/v1/app-info/app/website/website/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/v1/app-info/app/website/ui/static>
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

**AND IT GIVES ME** `Page not found (404)` **FOR STATIC FILES ONLY**

Can someone guide on howto fix it :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after doing so many trials, I have come to the conclusion that the major issue is in APACHE configuration.

Replacing the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test_site.com.conf` content with below fixed my problem.

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/v1/website-info/app/website/website/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/v1/website-info/app/website

<Directory /home/ubuntu/v1/website-info/app/website/website>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/v1/website-info/app/website/ui/static/

<Directory /home/ubuntu/v1/website-info/app/website/ui/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: This worked for me also. I had to add the Alias line to point to my static directory.